# String match Col2, check Col1 (same row) for value, apply function if FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching, dplyr

I'm pretty new to R/RStudio and brand new to stack overflow so bear with me if I'm not doing this all perfectly. I tried searching and couldn't find what I wanted so... on to the problem at hand:

I have a data frame (stored as tibble: 15,040 x 13) with col1 = com_id and col2 = com_desc. There are ~470 unique com_id/desc then it starts over (for the next time frame). The first ~64 unique IDs have a leading zero, the rest do not (and **absolutely can not** since there's both "011 - Field Crops" & "11 - Coal"). Data pulled for some time frames already have the leading zero, but several do not. Here's a subset of the first 2 columns of the data frame.

```
DF <- tribble(
  ~com_id, ~com_desc,
  "01", "FARM PRODUCTS",
  "011", "FIELD CROPS",
  "0112", "COTTON,RAW",
  "01131", "BARLEY",
  "01132", "CORN, EXCEPT POPCORN",
  "09131", "SHELLS (OYSTER,CRAB,ETC.)",
  "098", "FISH HATCHERIES, FARMS",
  "107", "TUNGSTEN ORES",
  "108", "CHROMIUM ORES",
  "109", "MISCELLANEOUS METAL ORES",
  "11", "COAL",
  "111", "ANTHRACITE",
  "1", "FARM PRODUCTS",
  "11", "FIELD CROPS",
  "112", "COTTON,RAW",
  "1131", "BARLEY",
  "1132", "CORN, EXCEPT POPCORN",
  "9131", "SHELLS (OYSTER,CRAB,ETC.)",
  "98", "FISH HATCHERIES, FARMS",
  "108", "CHROMIUM ORES",
  "109", "MISCELLANEOUS METAL ORES",
  "11", "COAL",
  "111", "ANTHRACITE")
```

Using the following function

```
pad.left <- function(DF, char = '0'){ DF %>% 
    mutate(com_id = ifelse(com_desc %in% "FARM PRODUCTS" & !str_detect(com_id, "^0"), 
                       str_pad(com_id, str_length(com_id) + 1, "left", char), com_id))
}
view(pad.left(DF))
```

I get the output

```
DF <- tribble(
  ~com_id, ~com_desc,
  "01", "FARM PRODUCTS",
  "011", "FIELD CROPS",
  "0112", "COTTON,RAW",
  "01131", "BARLEY",
  "01132", "CORN, EXCEPT POPCORN",
  "09131", "SHELLS (OYSTER,CRAB,ETC.)",
  "098", "FISH HATCHERIES, FARMS",
  "107", "TUNGSTEN ORES",
  "108", "CHROMIUM ORES",
  "109", "MISCELLANEOUS METAL ORES",
  "11", "COAL",
  "111", "ANTHRACITE",
  "01", "FARM PRODUCTS",    # Added zero!
  "11", "FIELD CROPS",
  "112", "COTTON,RAW",
  "1131", "BARLEY",
  "1132", "CORN, EXCEPT POPCORN",
  "9131", "SHELLS (OYSTER,CRAB,ETC.)",
  "98", "FISH HATCHERIES, FARMS",
  "108", "CHROMIUM ORES",
  "109", "MISCELLANEOUS METAL ORES",
  "11", "COAL",
  "111", "ANTHRACITE")
```

So I'm getting close, but I need `pad.left` to apply to 65 rows (or until it reaches com_desc = 'FISH HATCHERIES') when it activates instead of just padding one row. I'm not sure the best way to go about that.

Comment: Hi, first of all, you should provide some reproducible data. There are several ways to do it: manually create a dataframe (with ```data.frame()``` for example) and copy-paste the code in your post, use some data already available in R such as ```mtcars``` or ```iris```, or take a sample of your own data and create the code to reproduce it with the ```dput``` function (and then copy-paste it here). With reproducible data, it is much more easier to see why your code doesn't work because we just have to copy and paste your code in R to be at the same point as you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I updated my function and shared the output I get from using it, I can't share the whole data set and I'm not sure how to best replicate this other than sharing the data subset I provided already...

Comment: I haven't completely understood your question but you can make a small fake dataset which resembles your current dataset. So if after 470 unique com_id/desc it starts over in your fake dataset you can reset after 5. create 2-3 such groups and share data using `dput` (`dput(df)`) and show expected output for that data.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I used `tribble` to turn what I already shared into a tibble. Now you should be able to copy/paste data and function to run with. I need a way to make my function run until it finds com_desc = "FISH HATCHERIES" instead of only affecting the cell in the same row as "FARM PRODUCTS"

Comment: DF[1:65,]<-DF[1:65,]%>%mutate(com_id = ifelse(!str_detect(com_id, "^0"), str_pad(com_id, str_length(com_id) + 1, "left", '0'), com_id))